# Enable openmp support for CLion using CMake

Tags: mingw, clion

I've not been able to get my IDE to accept and compile OpenMP code. I tried to make changes inside the CMakeLists.txt file of the project as suggested in other questions but it did not work . After that I tried to compile the program using command line . Had no luck as it said gcc is not recognized as an internal or external command. I have downloaded gcc compiler through MingW installer and I have used it to compile c and c++ programs on CLion.

Can someone point me to a detailed guide or explain how to do it properly ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with any of your tags.  The question is how to set up CLion to use mingw on Windows, or maybe how to install gcc/mingw on Windows.

Comment: @nemequ: According to this phrase `I have downloaded gcc compiler through MingW installer and I have used it to compile c and c++ programs on CLion.` I thought that the asker has working gcc. But know I'm not so sure. It is actually unclear what the asker has and what he asks.

Comment: Based on the fact "gcc is not recognized as an internal or external command", I don't think OP has it properly installed. Anyways, the original tags were c, cmake, and openmp, which are definitely not appropriate; OP isn't yet to the point where those are relevant.

Comment: The tags might have been wrong. All I want is to be able to compile OpenMP code . I have a working gcc install. I have been writing and compiling c and c++ programs for a while now.